# How to compare element from two ArraylList in java 8

Tags: java, arraylist, java-8

```
    List<String> stringlist = new ArrayList<>();
    stringlist.add("Arjun");
    stringlist.add("Arohi");

    List<Student> studentList = new ArrayList<>();
    studentList.add(new Student("Arjun"));
    studentList.add(new Student("Arohi"));
```

please remember object type is different *Student* and String

I tried this but it doesn't work for me please suggest.

```
System.out.println(studentList.stream().allMatch(student->stringlist.contains(student.getName())));
```

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work"? Is there an error, or did it output something unexpected? If there is an error, what is the error message? If it outputs something unexpected, what did it output and what did you expect? You can [edit] the question to add this information.

Comment: Try with ```anyMatch``` instead of allMatch and check that both lists have the same size

Answer (score 1):

I would first convert stringList to HashSet as contains would be faster, and then use as below,

```
  HashSet<String> stringHashSet = new HashSet<>(stringlist);
    studentList.stream()
            .map(Student::getName)
            .allMatch(stringHashSet::contains);
```

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 ways to achieve the required result, the difference is in the time and space complexity (lets imagine that the sizes of two lists are similar, so we can measure each size as n):

1. Comparing the ArrayList-s directly:

   - Time complexity: O(n^2)
   - Space complexity: O(1)

```
public boolean containsAll(List<String> stringList, List<Student> studentList) {
    if (stringList.size() != studentList.size()) {
        return false;
    }

    return studentList.stream()
            .map(Student::getName)
            .allMatch(stringList::contains);
}
```

2. Converting one of the ArrayList-s (a String one) to HashSet to use the benefit of a hash data structure:

   - Time complexity: O(n)
   - Space complexity: O(n)

```
public boolean containsAll(List<String> stringList, List<Student> studentList) {
    if (stringList.size() != studentList.size()) {
        return false;
    }

    Set<String> stringSet = new HashSet<>(stringList);

    return studentList.stream()
            .map(Student::getName)
            .allMatch(stringSet::contains);
}
```

The difference in a time complexity exists due to the performance of the contains(...) method of ArrayList and HashSet: 
- it takes n steps for ArrayList to check whether the element is there as it goes through the entire collection step by step
- it takes 1 step for HashSet to make the same check by usage the hash function ([HashTable wikipedia link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table) for more details)

Speaking about the space: 
- no additional space is needed for the ArrayList approach
- HashSet requires additional space of size n, as a new collection is created

There is no answer, which approach is better. I would use the HashSet one if the size of ArrayList is not that huge, so there is a possibility to allocate an additional space. For the so called "big data" ArrayList-s I would go with the worse performance, but better memory usage (the ArrayList approach).